# How to call a PHP function itself?

Tags: php, wordpress, function

I have a file called "login.php". It's a little bit of PHP, which I found on the internet, and a login form. When the login button is fired, then the PHP should check the inputs wether they're valid or invalid.

I have solved this by redirecting to the actual file, so that it's refreshing the page. But this doens't work in wordpress, so I want to redirect to the actual PHP function.

My code looks like this:

```
<?php
     if ($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] == 'POST') {
     session_start();

     $username = $_POST['username'];
     $passwort = $_POST['passwort'];

     $hostname = $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'];
     $path = dirname($_SERVER['PHP_SELF']);

     // Benutzername und Passwort werden überprüft
     if ($username == 'admin' && $passwort == 'admin') {
        $_SESSION['angemeldet'] = true;

            // Weiterleitung zur geschützten Startseite
            if ($_SERVER['SERVER_PROTOCOL'] == 'HTTP/1.1') {
                if (php_sapi_name() == 'cgi') {
                    header('Status: 303 See Other');
                }
                else {
                    header('HTTP/1.1 303 See Other');
                }
            }

       header('downloadbereich.php');
       exit;
       }
      }
?>

<link href="login.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
<div class="contactForm" id="contactForm" style="width: 500px; margin: auto; float: left;">

<!--start contact form -->

<form name="myform" method="post" action="login.php<!-- this is what I want to remove-->">
    <p class="form" style="width: 245px; height: 116px; margin-right: 10px;"><input class="field" type="text" name="username" placeholder="Name" />
    <input class="field" type="password" autofocus name="passwort" placeholder="Passwort" />
    <button class="button" name="Submit">Login</button></p>

</form></div>
```

Comment: So... where's the function?

Comment: the function is the PHP above. I did not put it in a function, as I dont know how

Answer (score 0):

This doesn't work in WordPress for so many reasons. You can't just take a snippet of code and expect it to work for anything.

Anyway in WordPress there's a much simpler way. Delete this PHP / HTML and use:

```
<?php wp_login_form(); ?>
```

Details can be found here: http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_login_form

Comment: I actually wanted to create a theme template, which I then use!

Comment: This would go inside a template file.

Comment: cool thank you! I'm gonna check this! But do you know wether it is session-based?

Answer (score 0):

There are 2 option copy your file `login.php` file to your main directory like

eg. `localhost/YourFolderName/login.php`
edit the html form line

or just paste this line `<form name="myform" method="post" action="">`

Comment: <form name="myform" method="post" action="">

Comment: <form name="myform" method="post" action="http://localhost/YourProjectFolderName/login.php">

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
       <form name="myform" method="post" action="<?php echo $_SERVER['PHP_SELF']; ?>">
```